# I want to show product price in 1 pack but sale on whole cartoon pack in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento platform.

1) I want to show product and price (1 pack=10 pecs) like actual price 384 and special price 326.

2) but sale whole cartoon (1 cartoon=8 pack) like actual price 3072 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the qty increments option.
So, set the price per pack in your store. (384 in your case) and in the inventory tab of the product, enable qty increments and tell magento that the product can be sold only in increments of 8 (your cartoon).